# Text image link hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I'm trying to write code that shows text over image and I'm trying to achieve an hover effect. I post the code at http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/LVxmBG so that you can take a look to see how it works. As you can see, when you hover over the image, it darkened, but the text background isn't affected. Likewise, when you hover over the text background, the image effect isn't activated. I wanted to connect them together but how? It looks like that I might have to edit the html, I think?

Html code:

```
<div class="fourcolumns">
        <div class="productpic">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SZen19w.png" alt="Scuba">
            <h2 class="captioncolumn"><span>SCUBA</span></h2>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.fourcolumns { width: 100%; position: relative; margin: 40px 0;}
.productpic { width: 25%; float: left; display: inline-block; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #000000;}
.productpic a { }
.productpic img { width: 100%; opacity: 1;}
.productpic img:hover { opacity: 0.5;}
.productpic .captioncolumn { width: 80%; /*height: 50px;*/ background-color: #ffffff; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0; opacity: 1; padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;}
.productpic .captioncolumn span { font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-weight: 300; font-size: 36px; position: relative; color: #2a286a; opacity: 1; }
.productpic .captioncolumn:hover { opacity: 0.5;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all boils down to a link which ties everything together so that no matter which area of the box are hovered over, it's all activated, instead of one area, when hovered over, showing a hover effect and other areas not showing a hover effect. However, I don't want the text box to be affected in the hover effect. Therefore I looked around for answer for making only the child element activated inside the a parent link. Here's the answer:

```
.productpic a:hover img { opacity:0.5; }
```

You can also see the final result at http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/MwJzqO?editors=110

Answer (score 1):

Use this will help
    .productpic img:hover .productpic .captioncolumn,.productpic img { opacity: 0.5;}

Answer (score 0):

Okay.As per your comment the suggestion is to use the way-

```
.productpic img:hover + h2{ background:transparent;}
.productpic img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/87v1wuk8/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but the text is now transparent when hovered. I wanted the text to be solid but the white background to be transparent.